# Font loader postcss

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, fonts, postcss

I cannot get fonts to load up with postcss.

I have the font files in my src directory like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYCym.png

My css file looks like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Boxley ;
    src: url(./fonts/Boxley.ttf), format('ttf');
}
@font-face{
    font-family: Boxley-Bold;
    src: url(./fonts/Boxley-Bold.ttf), format('ttf');
}
```

etc.
My Postcss.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('precss'),
        require("css-mqpacker"),
        require("postcss-cssnext"),
        require("cssnano"),
        require("rucksack-css"),
        require("postcss-font-magician")({
        hosted: ['./src/css/fonts']
    })]
}
```

and my webpack file looks like this:

```
module: {
    rules: [{   
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        { 
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders:ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'postcss-loader']),
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'postcss-loader']),               
        },
    ]
},
```

i don't have any issues when it compiles

Answer (score -2):

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Boxley;
    src: url(fonts/Boxley.ttf), format('ttf');
}

@font-face{
    font-family: Boxley-Bold;
    src: url(fonts/Boxley-Bold.ttf), format('ttf');
}
```

your CSS file is in the same directory as fonts sub-folder and your are using src attribute...  check [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/).